# Passed bundle on Android, every key is null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, null, bundle

I'm trying to pass some values from an activity to another using this code:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putInt("x_element",xElementBar.getProgress());
    bundle.putInt("y_element",yElementBar.getProgress());
    bundle.putInt("frames",framesBar.getProgress());

    bundle.putInt("radioID", radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    bundle.putBoolean("sound", soundCheck.isChecked());
    bundle.putBoolean("vibrate",vibrateCheck.isChecked());

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    startActivity(intent);
```

And displaying the values on another activity using this code :

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    columnsText.setText("El número de columnas es: " + bundle.getString("x_element"));
    rowText.setText("El número de filas es: " + bundle.getString("y_element"));
    optionsText.setText("El número de opciones es: " + bundle.getString("frames"));

    styleText.setText("Se mostrarán: " + (bundle.getInt("radioID") == R.id.radioNumbers?"números":"colores"));

    soundText.setText("El sonido esta: " + (bundle.getBoolean("sound")?"activado":"desactivado"));
    vibrateText.setText("La vibración esta: " + (bundle.getBoolean("vibrate")?"activada":"desactivada"));
```

But every bundle.getX(ID) returns a null, crashing on the comparation with R.id.radioNumbers and displaying null on the rest.

The TextViews(columnsText, etc) are declared and linked before creating the bundle on the second activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're saving the fields as one type and retrieving them as another:

Sender:

```
bundle.putInt("x_element",xElementBar.getProgress());
```

Receiver:

```
columnsText.setText("El número de columnas es: " + bundle.getString("x_element"));
```

The type has to match, so change the receiver to be `bundle.getInt("x_element")` to get the data then convert it to `String`.